# no endpoints available for service for kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

According to following information, `kubernetes-dashboard` is creaded. I start `kubectl prox` to access the dashboard

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf created
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created
[root@master ~]# kubectl proxy --address="192.168.88.43" -p 8001 --accept-hosts='^*$'
Starting to serve on 192.168.88.43:8001
```

when I go below url

```
http://192.168.88.43:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

i get the

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying it takes too long? Also where are you running the k8s and what are the specs of the cluster?

Comment: @Crou I cannot go kubernetes-dashboard ui. In API list I did not see "/ui" in api list. But, I successfylly apply `kubectl apply -f ....`http://....kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`

Comment: @Crou I updated the my question

Comment: Seems like the deployment did not worked, you can check the `kubectl get po` and see if pods are running

Comment: Have you deployed CNI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you followed the [Deploying the Dashboard UI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui) but, you did not follow the whole installation process [Creating a single master cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm) correctly.

You might have missed:

> You should now deploy a pod network to the cluster.
>
> Run "kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml" with one of the options listed at:
>
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/

You can follow the Kubernetes documentation on how to [Installing a pod network add-on](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network).

Once done, you can verify if CNI is deployed and working using `kubectl -n kube-system get pods`.

If everything goes correctly your `kubernetes-dashboard` should be healthy and working.

Comment: Concretely, you can install Calio which is a CNI: `kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml`

After few seconds of installing, you should see your node is ready: `kubectl get nodes`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to find the status of dashboard and its name.

kubectl get pods -n kube-system

kubernetes-dashboard-8y59ns938y0           0/1     Pending   0          57m

After that you can run a describe command on it to see whats wrong with the pod like the following.

kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-8y59ns938y0  -n kube-system

From the Message you should be able to figure out the reason why the dashboard is not working

Comment: kubectl get pods --all-namespaces # the dashboard is under kubernetes-dashboard namespace